# Finding a representation of a Lie algebra given its weight - easier methods?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

My understanding is from using both Humphreys and Fulton-Harris.

Usually, given a Lie algebra (in this case, I want to take $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_3 (\mathbb{C})$) and an irreducible representation $V$, we decompose $V$ into its weight spaces with respect to some Cartan (again in this case, $\mathfrak{h}$ is the diagonal traceless matrices), then find a highest weight vector killed by all positive weight spaces (fixing an ordering on roots beforehand), and this tells us the weight of $V$.

In the other direction, given some weight $\lambda$, the usual construction is to build a (huge) highest weight module $Z(\lambda)$ and quotient this out by its unique maximal submodule to get the desired representation $V(\lambda)$. In practice however, this seems more complicated to me than it could be.

The specific example I want to work with is using the weight $\lambda = (1,0,-1)$ in the weight space with basis given by $L_i$ matrices which send a diagonal matrix to its $i$-th entry. The corresponding representation is the adjoint rep, $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ acting on itself.

I know from results given in e.g. Fulton-Harris, the representations are contained in a tensors of symmetric powers of the various wedge products of the standard representation $V = \mathbb{C}^3$ - however, I can't see how $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ lives in this tensor product.

So, my question is:

> Is there a simpler way of seeing that the weight $(1,0,-1)$ corresponds to $V = \mathfrak{sl}_3$? What about other weights, such as $(3,0,0)$ which corresponds to the symmetric algebra, or $(1,1,1)$?

The only way I see this to work is to 'guess' a highest weight vector. In the $(1,0,-1)$ case, I can 'guess' that $V = \mathfrak{sl}_3$, and then find the highest weight vector to be a matrix with 1 in the top right entry. Same as in $(3,0,0)$, I can 'guess' the highest weight monomial. But this won't work for other examples, so I'm looking for something a bit more concrete.

Comment: What kind of answer are you after? If you know that $V$ is irreducible, you could plot the weights of $V$ and then find the highest weight under the partial ordering $\leq$ on weights. In the particular case of the adjoint representation, its highest weight will always be the highest root of the root system. In general though one needs to do some work to find highest weights, and often finding the common kernel of the positive root operators is straightforward.

Comment: I'm struggling to work through the example in what the irrep associated to the weight $(1,1,1)$ is - this is the essence of my question. I'm not too familiar with the terminology, is there a better way of phrasing this?

Comment: For $\mathfrak{sl}_3$, the weight $(1, 1, 1)$ is the same as the weight $(0, 0, 0)$, so the representation you are looking for is the trivial representation. If you were working with $\mathfrak{gl}_3$ instead, the weight $(1, 1, 1)$ would be the highest weight of the one-dimensional determinant representation.

Comment: Right, so for this example in particular, if I'm given $(1,1,1)$, how do I find out that it's the determinant representation (without knowing the weight of that rep)? i.e. how do I get from a weight to an irrep?

Comment: Going from a weight to an irrep is a difficult problem. There is an algebraic construction via Verma modules (which you've already noted is a bit impractical to compute with). For $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ and $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ there are certain _Schur functors_ which will eat a highest weight and give you back an irreducible representation (you can read Chapter 8 of Fulton's _Young Tableaux_ to learn about these). There are generalisations of Young tableaux to the other semisimple Lie algebras too.

Comment: If you rephrase the problem as "Given a highest weight, output a vector space with a basis and a $\mathfrak{g}$-action on that basis", then I think something like Young tableaux are the best possible answer. They're still not necessarily easy to compute with, but you know the size of the basis and weight spaces then at least.